# Is it possible to call S4 method directly?

Tags: r

Trying to build a gausspr model and using predict to predict the output. Copying code from predict.gausspr documentation.

```
data(promotergene)

## create test and training set
ind <- sample(1:dim(promotergene)[1],20)
genetrain <- promotergene[-ind, ]
genetest <- promotergene[ind, ]

## train a support vector machine
gene <- gausspr(Class~.,data=genetrain,kernel="rbfdot",
                kpar=list(sigma=0.015))

## predict gene type probabilities on the test set
genetype <- predict(gene,genetest,type="probabilities")
```

This works fine. Now, when i try to call predict.gausspr directly it's failing. Is it possible to call  this S4 method directly ?
Also, is this case with any S4 method or something special in this case ?

```
> genetype <- predict.gausspr(gene,genetest,type="probabilities")
Error: could not find function "predict.gausspr"
```

`kernlab` package is loaded properly and am able to do `?predict.gausspr` and see the notes

Comment: `predict(gene, ...)` is the correct usage; why do you want to call it some other way?

Comment: Hmm ok. So, i have a case where gausspr model is not able to predict (giving numeric(0) as o/p). Normally i try debug these issues by calling methods directly and see where it's failing. But for this case direct call is failing, hence this question.

Comment: And now, it's also my itch to understand is it possible or not and reason behind it.

Comment: There is no function predict.gausspr, that's not how S4 methods work. I don't know why the kernlab author has provided a help page predict.gausspr. I've added information on debugging S4 methods to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean the `gausspr()` function from the kernlab package. Using the snippet from `?gausspr` I see

```
library(kernlab)
data(iris)
test <- gausspr(Species~., data=iris, var=2)
predict(test, iris[,-5])
```

`test` is indeed an S4 object

```
> isS4(test)
[1] TRUE
> class(test)
[1] "gausspr"
attr(,"package")
[1] "kernlab"
```

### Discovering S4 methods

S4 methods are discovered using `showMethods()` and `selectMethod()` (output edited for brevity)

```
> showMethods("predict")
Function: predict (package stats)
object="ANY"
object="gausspr"
object="kfa"
object="kha"
object="kpca"
object="kqr"
object="ksvm"
object="lssvm"
object="onlearn"
object="rvm"

> showMethods(class=class(test), where=search())
Function: alphaindex (package kernlab)
object="gausspr"

...
Function: predict (package stats)
object="gausspr"
...


> selectMethod("predict", class    Method Definition:

function (object, ...) 
{
    .local <- function (object, newdata, type = "response", coupler = "minpair") 
    {
        sc <- 0
        type <- match.arg(type, c("response", "probabilities", 
            "votes", "variance"))
...
```

If there was no relevant predict,gausspr method, then we would end up at predict,ANY-method, which actually invokes the S3 methods discovered by `methods("predict")`.

The help page is discovered with

```
?"predict,gausspr-method"
```

### Debugging S4 methods

#### traceback / recover

If a method fails and you'd like to debug it, then usually the simplest thing to do is to use `?traceback` to find out where the error occurs, and `?recover` to identify the problem in more detail. Here's an error

```
> predict(test, mtcars)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Sepal.Length' not found
```

and we can see the 'call stack' from 1 (the generic 'predict') to 2 (the method 'predict,gausspr-mehtod') to 3 (the .local function, defined inside the gausspr method), etc.

```
> traceback()
9: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
8: eval(predvars, data, env)
7: model.frame.default(object, data, xlev = xlev)
6: model.frame(object, data, xlev = xlev)
5: model.matrix.default(delete.response(terms(object)), as.data.frame(newdata), 
       na.action = na.action)
4: model.matrix(delete.response(terms(object)), as.data.frame(newdata), 
       na.action = na.action)
3: .local(object, ...)
2: predict(test, mtcars)
1: predict(test, mtcars)
```

Set the `error` option (see `?options`) to `recover` and try again, choosing the frame number inside the `.local` function to be in the body of the method.

```
> options(error=recover)
> predict(test, mtcars)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Sepal.Length' not found

Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

1: predict(test, mtcars)
2: predict(test, mtcars)
3: .local(object, ...)
4: model.matrix(delete.response(terms(object)), as.data.frame(newdata), na.act
5: model.matrix.default(delete.response(terms(object)), as.data.frame(newdata)
6: model.frame(object, data, xlev = xlev)
7: model.frame.default(object, data, xlev = xlev)
8: eval(predvars, data, env)
9: eval(expr, envir, enclos)

Selection: 3
Called from: eval(predvars, data, env)
Browse[1]> ls()
[1] "coupler" "ncols"   "newdata" "nrows"   "object"  "oldco"   "sc"     
[8] "type"
```

Restore normal error behavior with `options(error=NULL)`.

#### debug / trace

There are a couple of things to do to debug S4 methods. The first is to use the debugger on the selected methods

```
debug(selectMethod("predict", class(test)))
```

The second is to trace the method

```
trace("predict", browser, signature=class(test))
```

(stop tracing with `untrace("predict", signature=class(test))`

In this particular case you'll see that the body of the function is in a nested function called `.local`. Setting the debugger on the outer function is not enough, instead one needs to break in the outer function, then step through until .local has been *defined* but not *evaluated*, and set the debugger on .local, like (editing the output for brevity)

```
> trace(predict, browser, signature=class(test))
Tracing specified method for function "predict" in environment
<namespace:stats>
Warning: Tracing only in the namespace; to untrace you will need:
untrace("predict", where = getNamespace("stats"))
[1] "predict"
attr(,"package")
[1] "stats"
> predict(test, iris[,-5])
Tracing predict(test, iris[, -5]) on entry 
Called from: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
Browse[1]> n
debug: {
    .local <- function (object, newdata, type = "response", coupler = "minpair") 
    {
        sc <- 0
        type <- match.arg(type, c("response", "probabilities", 
...
Browse[2]> n
debug: .local(object, ...)
Browse[2]> debug(.local)
Browse[2]> n
debugging in: .local(object, ...)
debug: {
    sc <- 0
    type <- match.arg(type, c("response", "probabilities", "votes", 
...
Browse[3]>
```

The author of the kernlab package did *not* provide an S3-style function `predict.gausspr`, even though the S4 guidelines (`?setMethod`) suggest that they do. This would have simplified debugging, e.g., `debug(kernlab:::predict.gausspr)`.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I am building model using caret, so model object looks like > class(model) => [1] "train"         "train.formula", whereas predict.gausspr doc shows it accepts object of class 'gausspr', so when predict is called on this object, who extracts model$finalModel and then passes it to predict.gausspr ?

Comment: @MohitVerma modify your question with a simple reproducible and complete example (such as the four lines of code that start my answer) and clear question; it's too hard to figure out what you're asking from the comment.

Comment: Sure. Have rephrased my problem statement and added reproducible code. Sorry for the ambiguity.